# Java SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

PostgreSQL Function is called in the back-end database as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM prepend('abcdefg');
```

Calling PostgreSQL Function from front-end Java client as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM prepend('?');"
```

Will this cause SQL injection? Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

Don't want to use PreparedStatement. How about Java 8 Streams?

Comment: Yes, it will. Sstring interpolation/concatenation could lead to SQL Injection. You should use parametrized query.

Comment: Yes because the client can inject variables directly into the string you are using on prepend. Also called variable substitution.

Comment: Why is using a prepared statement not a solution here? Note that having a `getData` method that can be passed arbitrary queries in itself could already pose an injection risk.

Comment: I don't understand why PreparedStatements should not be possible as well but in every other case you have to check, validate and escape the `input` manually before querying.

Comment: What do you mean by _query is called from client_?

Answer (score 2):

Using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` is the best option. Here's a way to use `PreparedStatement` in your case,

```
String input = "abcdefg";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM prepend(?)");
ps.setString(1, String.format("%s", input));
```

Comment: Isn't `String.format("%s", input)` the same as just `input`? What's the use of the `format()` function here?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes. I used that just because op has used it. May be he uses `String.format` in the proper way, but showing us just an example.

Comment: And I was thinking whether op misunderstood that he cannot use PreparedStatements because his query is created using `String.format`. `String.format("SELECT * FROM prepend('%s');", input);`